# Cordova: always deviceready has not fired

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have another problem with Cordova. I want to use the plugins "cordova.custom.plugins.exitapp" and "cordova-plugins-printer" in Cordova 7.1.0. 

On the server side, I have build document.AddEventListener into  `$(document).ready(function() {});`

**.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

...

document.addEventListener("deviceready", exitFromApp, false);

...

}),


function exitFromApp() {

    console.log("NAVIGATOR: " + navigator);
    console.log("NAVIGATOR.APP: " + navigator.app);
    console.log("NAVIGATOR.APP.EXITAPP: " + navigator.app.exitApp());

    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Whether I use addEventListener or not, the Android Studio always says:
- deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
- Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
- Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

But the difference is that `addEventListener` does not call the `exitFromApp()` function. 
When I call `exitFromApp()` directly, it works, but navigator.app is undefined (or cordova.plugins / window.plugins is undefined).
The cordova.js is called in the header.php and is therefore always available.

If I use the plugins via index.html on the tablet, it works.

I have set the permissions in **config.xml**:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

**Installation:**

Cordova 7.1.0

cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.1

cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3

cordova.custom.plugin.exitapp 1.0.0

phonegap.plugin-barcodescanner 7.0.1

cordova-plugin-printer 0.7.3

Answer (score 1):

the `deviceready` event is fired before `$(document).ready()` You want to do you stuff after both have been fired.. try this..

```
var DomReady = new Promise(done=>$(document).ready(done));
var deviceReady = new Promise(done=>document.addEventListener("deviceready", done, false));
Promise.all[DomReady, deviceReady].then(()=>{
  // both device and dom are ready
});
```

... Or you could just put the deviceReady call outside the documetnt ready call since I'm sure the device ready will always be first.